# Is Organizational Politics on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

According to the [Help Center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), this stack "is for objective questions about governments, policies and political processes." it later observes that:

> For purposes of this site, we define politics as:
>
> The end result of conflicting egos working themselves out through matters of policy.

A list of examples follows, which notes that Macroeconomics is in scope (even though Macroeconomics is not *solely* government-focused).

Are *political* questions about *non-governmental* organizations, polities, associations, etc. on-topic? This could include questions about why and how private and/or non-governmental organizations operate the way they do, such as with respect to leadership selection or internal governance, why organizations set their policies, procedures, or goals in the way they do (especially when such decisions are analogous in some way to decisions commonly made by governmental entities), or why organizations, or factions within organizations, act the way they do (de facto) despite lacking any formal policy requiring them to do so.

Example questions:

> Religion X follows this really convoluted procedure for electing bishops involving multiple rounds of voting over a six month period. Have they ever explained why they have chosen this method over something simpler or closer to the processes used by similar organizations?
>
> Employer Y has a strict policy of firing any worker who reticulates the spline without using the correct cover sheet, even on a first offense. Does any empirical data exist which indicate that this sort of "zero tolerance" policy increases profit?
>
> Why does Private University ABC use instructors from the Math Department to teach Physics? I heard a rumor that this was related somehow to a union dispute, is there any truth to this?
>
> Why do model railroading clubs in Podunktown rarely allow non-members to speak at meetings? Is this "just the way it has always been done" or is there a specific origin to this practice?
>
> Mt. Whatever Private Boarding School for Gifted Children organizes a weekly march around town where students chant the school cheer during Monday morning rush hour. When and by whom was this practice started?
>
> The Standard Code of Policies and Procedures of First Street Baptist Church of Anystown, New York, Revised Code AD 1792 requires the pastor to "organize an appropriate Christmas activity according to his professional discretion", but the church has not done a Christmas tree lighting ceremony since before the US Civil War. Why? Is there some sort of *unwritten* policy on this or is this just some weird, random coincidence? Are local legends that several children were killed by a falling Christmas tree in 1835 related in some way to this?

Comment: I think this was discussed on Meta earlier? don't recall detais

Comment: @user4012 I searched and didn't find anything. If you can find something, propose closure as a duplicate and I will accept it.

Comment: I note that some of your example questions are rather historical in nature.